# spring .getBean(...) in a struts app without main method

Tags: java, spring, struts-1

My question is very simple:

I have a Struts web app that I created that uses Spring for the dependency injection and Hibernate integration.

This app has no main method.

From what I understand I need this in my app (usually placed in the main method)... they say Spring needs to create the first bean like this.

```
MyClass myClass = applicationContext.getBean("myClass");
```

Other than placing this code in the Action servlet from Struts (it works when I do that), is there any way to get rid of it? When I get rid of it by doing this:

```
@Autowire
MyClass myClass;

...
...
myClass.doSomething();
```

I get null pointer exceptions and no beans get injected.

If there is no way to get rid of getBean, where is it used in a web app that DOES NOT have a main method?

Comment: You're not describing how you're attempting to integrate Spring into your Struts app.  (Nor indicating the version of Struts outer Sorting you're using.) While Struts 1 is book longer supported by Showing directly, IIRC, Struts 2 has trivial support via the Spring plugin.

Comment: struts 1.3, spring 3.2, hibernate 4.x. it's a simple CRUD test app with hibernate.

Comment: (Again IIRC) Spring 3 has direct Struts 1 support and its usage is detailed in the Spring docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without your Struts actions making any explicit calls to Spring to get the beans (we use [WebApplicationContextUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html)), [this article](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#struts) describes the other two options:

> 1. Configure Spring to manage your Actions as beans, using the ContextLoaderPlugin, and set their dependencies in a Spring context
>      file.
> 2. Subclass Spring's ActionSupport classes and grab your Spring-managed beans explicitly using a getWebApplicationContext()
>      method.

2 doesn't avoid what I think you're trying to avoid: having Spring awareness in your Struts actions. (Although `@Autowired` is a Spring-specific annotation too.)

I have no idea how 1 interacts with your struts-config.xml, like if you have to duplicate actions in both places.

We decided that explicitly asking Spring for one or two high level beans ("facades"), in our application's base Action class, was the simplest approach.